# SQL command to treat 0 as negative and 1 as positive

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working with DB where someone made it like this:

There is a field named VOTE which stores an upvote or a downvote, and then a bunch of metadata about the vote.

There is a column in this table called UP which is BOOL which represents "Is this an Upvote?" and it is have value of 1 if the entry is an Upvote, but it has 0 is the entry is a Downvote.

So when I run a query on this table, I want to create a total sum which treat the 1 as +1 and the 0 as -1, so if there are 5 of each it ends up being 0 for instance.

Is there nice MYSQL way to do this in 1 single command? Perhaps it is very bad to design table with this "IS IT UPVOTE?" boolean and maybe the whole table has to be redesigned?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use a `case` statement:

```
select sum(case when `up` = 1 then 1 when `up` = 0 then -1 end)
```

I mean, you could get fancy, and do something like this:

```
select sum(2 * `up` - 1)
```

but that is rather inscrutable.

or even:

```
select sum(`up` = 1) - sum(`up` = 0)
```

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza . . . It converts "1" to "1" and "0" to "-1".

Comment: The 3rd thing you suggest looks good actually, does it have any downside, performance-wiuse perhaps, or is the same essentially?

Comment: Cocorico, best way is write the query and run the `explain`

Comment: @Cocorico . . . All of these should be pretty similar in terms of performance.  They should scan the table once for the aggregation result, and t he additional logic should pale in comparison to simple arithmetic or a `case` statement.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
(
SELECT COUNT(Up) AS VoteCount
FROM votetable WHERE VOTE=1
)-
(
SELECT COUNT(Up) AS VoteCount
FROM votetable WHERE VOTE=0
)
```